# XML parsing in Python using Python 2 or 3

Tags: python

I'm just trying to write a simple program to allow me to parse some of the following XML.
So far in following examples I am not getting the results I'm looking for.

I encounter many of these XML files and I generally want the info after a handful of tags.
What's the best way using elementtree to be able to do a search for `<Id>` and grab what ever info is in that tag. I was trying things like

```
for Reel in root.findall('Reel'):
...     id = Reel.findtext('Id')
...     print id
```

Is there a way just to look for every instance of `<Id>` and grab the urn: etc that comes after it? Some code that traverses everything and looks for `<what I want>` and so on.

This is a very truncated version of what I usually deal with.

This didn't get what I wanted at all. Is there an easy just to match `<what I want>` in any XML file and get the contents of that tag, or do i need to know the structure of the XML well enough to know its relation to Root/child etc?

```
 <Reel>
 <Id>urn:uuid:632437bc-73f9-49ca-b687-fdb3f98f430c</Id>
 <AssetList>
  <MainPicture>
   <Id>urn:uuid:46afe8a3-50be-4986-b9c8-34f4ba69572f</Id>
   <EditRate>24 1</EditRate>
   <IntrinsicDuration>340</IntrinsicDuration>
   <EntryPoint>0</EntryPoint>
   <Duration>340</Duration>
   <FrameRate>24 1</FrameRate>
   <ScreenAspectRatio>2048 858</ScreenAspectRatio>
  </MainPicture>
  <MainSound>
   <Id>urn:uuid:1fce0915-f8c7-48a7-b023-36e204a66ed1</Id>
   <EditRate>24 1</EditRate>
   <IntrinsicDuration>340</IntrinsicDuration>
   <EntryPoint>0</EntryPoint>
   <Duration>340</Duration>
  </MainSound>
 </AssetList>
</Reel>
```

@Mata that worked perfectly, but when I tried to use that for different values on another XML file I fell flat on my face. For instance, what about this section of a file.I couldn't post the whole thing unfortunately. What if I want to grab what comes after KeyId?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><DCinemaSecurityMessage xmlns="http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-KDM-20040311#" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
  <!-- Generated by Wailua Version 0.3.20 -->
  <AuthenticatedPublic Id="ID_AuthenticatedPublic">
    <MessageId>urn:uuid:7bc63f4c-c617-4d00-9e51-0c8cd6a4f59e</MessageId>
    <MessageType>http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-KDM-20040311#</MessageType>
    <AnnotationText>SPIDERMAN-3_FTR_S_EN-XX_US-13_51_4K_PH_20070423_DELUXE ~ KDM for Quvis-10010.pem</AnnotationText>
    <IssueDate>2007-04-29T04:13:43-00:00</IssueDate>
    <Signer>
      <dsig:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=BzC0n/VV/uVrl2PL3uggPJ9va7Q=,CN=.deluxe-admin-c,OU=.mxf-j2c.ca.cinecert.com,O=.ca.cinecert.com</dsig:X509IssuerName>
      <dsig:X509SerialNumber>10039</dsig:X509SerialNumber>
    </Signer>
    <RequiredExtensions>
      <Recipient>
        <X509IssuerSerial>
          <dsig:X509IssuerName>dnQualifier=RUxyQle0qS7qPbcNRFBEgVjw0Og=,CN=SM.QuVIS.com.001,OU=QuVIS Digital Cinema,O=QuVIS.com</dsig:X509IssuerName>
          <dsig:X509SerialNumber>363</dsig:X509SerialNumber>
        </X509IssuerSerial>
        <X509SubjectName>CN=SM MD LE FM.QuVIS_CinemaPlayer-3d_10010,OU=QuVIS,O=QuVIS.com,dnQualifier=3oBfjTfx1me0p1ms7XOX\+eqUUtE=</X509SubjectName>
      </Recipient>
      <CompositionPlaylistId>urn:uuid:336263da-e4f1-324e-8e0c-ebea00ff79f4</CompositionPlaylistId>
      <ContentTitleText>SPIDERMAN-3_FTR_S_EN-XX_US-13_51_4K_PH_20070423_DELUXE</ContentTitleText>
      <ContentKeysNotValidBefore>2007-04-30T05:00:00-00:00</ContentKeysNotValidBefore>
      <ContentKeysNotValidAfter>2007-04-30T10:00:00-00:00</ContentKeysNotValidAfter>
      <KeyIdList>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:9851b0f6-4790-0d4c-a69d-ea8abdedd03d</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:8317e8f3-1597-494d-9ed8-08a751ff8615</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:5d9b228d-7120-344c-aefc-840cdd32bbfc</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:1e32ccb2-ab0b-9d43-b879-1c12840c178b</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:44d04416-676a-2e4f-8995-165de8cab78d</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:906da0c1-b0cb-4541-b8a9-86476583cdc4</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:0fe2d73a-ebe3-9844-b3de-4517c63c4b90</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:862fa79a-18c7-9245-a172-486541bef0c0</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:aa2f1a88-7a55-894d-bc19-42afca589766</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:59d6eeff-cd56-6245-9f13-951554466626</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:14a13b1a-76ba-764c-97d0-9900f58af53e</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:ccdbe0ae-1c3f-224c-b450-947f43bbd640</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:dcd37f10-b042-8e44-bef0-89bda2174842</KeyId>
        <KeyId>urn:uuid:9dd7103e-7e5a-a840-a15f-f7d7fe699203</KeyId>
      </KeyIdList>
    </RequiredExtensions>
    <NonCriticalExtensions/>
  </AuthenticatedPublic>
  <AuthenticatedPrivate Id="ID_AuthenticatedPrivate"><enc:EncryptedKey xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<enc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
<ds:DigestMethod xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
</enc:EncryptionMethod>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `Reel.findtext('Id')` only matches direct children of `Reel`. If you want to find all `Id` tags in your xml document, you can just use:

```
ids = [id.text for id in Reel.findall(".//Id")]
```

This would give you a list of all text nodes of all `Id` tags which are children of `Reel`.

---

edit:
Your updated example uses namespaces, in this case `KeyId` is in the default namespace (`http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-KDM-20040311#`), so to search for it you need to include it in your search:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

doc = ElementTree.parse('test.xml')
nsmap = {'ns': 'http://www.digicine.com/PROTO-ASDCP-KDM-20040311#'}
ids = [id.text for id in doc.findall(".//ns:KeyId", namespaces=nsmap)]
print(ids)
...
```

The xpath subset `ElementTree` supports is rather limited. If you want a more complete support, you should use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) instead, it's [xpath support](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) is way more complete.

For example, using xpath to search for all `KeyId` tags (ignoring namespaces) and returning their text content directly:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse('test.xml')
ids = doc.xpath(".//*[local-name()='KeyId']/text()")
print(ids)
...
```

Comment: but say I have a bunch of Id fields in the XML doc and I want the text/data that comes after Id. Sorry, I feel like I don't know enough about XML to use the correct vocab.

Comment: @user1124541 - I've added more examples, hope it helps. btw, your second xml fragment isn't valid, it misses some tags...

Comment: @mata-thanks. I'm realizing i just don't really understand the structure of these types of xml files. I wish i could post all of the file to ask more questions etc.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [XPath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) might be right up your alley - it will let you query your XML document for exactly what you're looking for, as long as you know the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I needed to do. This works for finding whatever I need.

```
for node in tree.getiterator():
...     if 'KeyId' in node.tag:
...             mylist = node.tag
...             print(mylist)
...
```